# Access VBA DCount data type mismatch in criteria expression when data types are obviously the same (both Text)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm doing a simple DCount, just looking for how many people have signed up for the same date and time.  At the moment I'm just using a single date and a single time to prove the process, then I'll have it loop through all possible dates and times.

```
Private Sub Get_Singles()
    Dim TestDate As String
    Dim TestTime As String
    AloneCnt = 0
    Dinc = 0
    Tinc = 0
    TestDate = vStartDate
    TestTime = "0700"
    
        If (DCount("[ID]", VigilTable, "[fldTime] = " & TestTime) = 1) Then
 '       "[fldDate] = " & TestDate) & " And
        AloneCnt = AloneCnt + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

It works fine for the date (I've moved it to a different line and commented it out so I can focus on the time.).

In the table, fldDate and fldTime are both set for text (shows up as Field Size
= 255 in the properties list) and, as you can see, TestDate and TestTime are both dimmed as String.

And it works if I change the DCount line to:

`(DCount("[ID]", VigilTable, "[fldTime] = '0700'")`

So where's the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error is, that you must handle date and time as data type Date. So change the data type of the fields to DateTime and:

```vb
    Dim TestDate As Date
    Dim TestTime As Date
    Dim AloneCnt As Long

    TestDate = vStartDate
    TestTime = TimeSerial(7, 0, 0)
    
    If DCount("*", "VigilTable", "[fldTime] = #" & Format(TestTime, "hh\:nn\:ss") & "# And [fldDate] = #" & Format(TestDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#") = 1 Then
        AloneCnt = AloneCnt + 1
    End If
```

Comment: Declaring them as Date type is where I started but they're damned hard to work with that way.  Until I hit this snag I used them as text types and it's worked.  Note that they are stored in the table as text and entered into the table from combo boxes where they are also displayed as text.  I suppose I could convert them to Date type for this short routine but I still have to use variables for the DCount.  And this works: ``` (DCount("[ID]", VigilTable, "[fldTime] = '0700'")``` so it doesn't look like the problem is with text but with using variables, no?

Comment: No. Dealing with dates as Date is not difficult, just learn how. Using anything else like text or numbers is a dead-end and will only lead to endless troubles and workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Because you hold all date/time bits as text/string, you should use the text syntax in the criteria as you showed: with quotes (notice the quotes around time string):

```
(DCount("[ID]", VigilTable, "[fldTime] = '" & TestTime & "'")
```

You could also keep Date/times in date types  like @Gustav's answer.

Update:

[image: Here is the full module]

You must be doing something wrong; here is my suggested version in VBA window, and it is not Red.

Comment: VBA didn't like that at all; turned it bright red.  I fiddled with it a bit but it stayed bright red.

Comment: Check your module against my example screenshot.

Comment: It would be a good investment for you to learn how to deal with date and time in Access SQL, and VBA, and switch to it; @Gustav gave you an excellent example in his answer.

Comment: I apparently failed to make myself clear.  I do know how to deal with date and time and have done so many times, including certain places in this project.

But for most of this project, plain text is just easier because if avoids the need for converting from text to date/time and back to text.  And certainly, as I suspected, using date/time would have helped not at all with this problem; that I haven't mastered where the single quotes go is what created this problem (that I could profitably spend some time learning, though I find it very confusing).

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't mean anything bad by that comment; apologies if I caused offence.

Comment: No offence taken.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the fix after searching several other sites; it was, as I suggested above, a problem of handling variables:

`If (DCount("[ID]", VigilTable, "[fldDate]='" & TestDate & "'" & " AND [fldTime] = '" & TestTime & "'") = 1) Then`

I always have trouble with those damned single quotes and can never get them in the right place (I'd tried placing single quotes several times but never got them where they are here.); I don't know if the rules are different in different places or I just don't understand the rules or both.

Thanks for all your suggestions; even things that don't work help.